# fetching values from map in jstl

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I have the following code on my jsp page:

```
<c:out value="${items}" /><br />

<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
     1. <c:out value="${item.key}" /><br />
     2. <c:out value="${item.key eq 70}" /><br />
     3. <c:out value="${items[70]}" /><br />
     4. <c:out value="${items[item.key]}" /><br />
</c:forEach>
```

And it produces the following output

```
{70=true}
1. 70
2. true
3.
4. true
```

And I just can't figure out why 3. is empty. Any ideas?

The map is of type `Map<Integer, Boolean>`

Comment: What are the types of the keys in the map?  `Integer`, `Long`, `Byte`, `Characater`, what?

Answer (score 3):

Basically autoboxing puts an Integer object into the Map.

```
map.put(new Integer(0), "myValue")
```

EL evaluates 0 as a Long and thus goes looking for a Long as the key in the map.
i.e. it evaluates:

```
map.get(new Long(0))
```

As a Long is never equal to an Integer object, it does not find the entry in the map.
That's it in a nutshell.

Refer forum http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9702932#9702932

Comment: Solution: use `Map<Long, Boolean>` instead.